# Correct packages installation without using Homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, python

I was reading this old post because I want to download a homebrew package without using brew : [How to download a binary from brew without installing brew?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/398618/how-to-download-a-binary-from-brew-without-installing-brew) but I'm stuck so I try to ask too.

I'm on homebrew formulae web page : https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/

So, I want to install the package `tcl-tk` to use `Tkinter` on my Mac (or any other package) so I search for it from search bar : https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tcl-tk#default

My binary location on internet is written inside JSON file at : https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/tcl-tk.json

Now I need to download binary files linked in `JSON file` (3rd line in this case) :`{"url":"https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/tcl/Tcl/8.6.11/tcl8.6.11-src.tar.gz"`

I think these must be placed somewhere inside `/usr/local/Cellar/`. For example I know that my binaries location should be something like : `/usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6...`

Now, the question is : should I copy them there with a `cp -R <package-name> /usr/local/Cellar/` or there is an installer somewhere that I can/must use? I think just copy them there isn't enough but maybe I'm wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: 1. Why not use brew? 2. Why not install from [source](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html)?

Comment: @JBallin I need to share my python desktop app with family and friends but to do this I need them to install python-tk and tcl-tk. My main problem is that they don't have brew so should I install it in their pc with a script? I could, all would be easier but I thought it would be better to install them only what is needed. Not install from source because I don't know how to do it, which steps I should do, I'm new but I'm looking for this also because it would be faster instead of install brew. I don't know do you have any suggestion?

Comment: A script is the simplest (I wrote one [here](https://github.com/JBallin/ballin-scripts/blob/master/install.sh) that prompts the user to install brew), but it requires that the end user trusts/understands what it’s doing. I don’t see a reason not to install brew - not worth making it harder for them/you. In addition to the script you could record a demo explaining how to install it manually using brew as well.

Comment: Why would you install an entire package manager just to get Tk?  Further, I wonder how well grabbing homebrew's Tk would work without homebrew's python of some ilk.  Finally, where are you getting a reasonable Python from?  If you intend to use the python 2.7 that Apple ships, it already includes Tk.

Comment: @JBallin I know that using brew is the simplest solution but downloading all the entire package manager just to get Tk...I would like to keep this as last solution and it that case your script could be useful but can we create a script that doesn't ask to the user to know he's installing brew? I don't think they're interested

Comment: @MarcWilson downloading brew it's the last option I would like to avoid it but is also true that installing brew packages without brew...So as JBallin suggested I could install it from source maybe there is an installer. I'm using python3 because I read that old versions of Tk now are broken on BigSur (or newest MacOS versions)

Comment: You're installing Python3 *from where* and why doesn't that provide Tk?  All installers from python.org provide Tk as documented here https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/